# Loop through JavaScript array accessing objects with different IDs

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having trouble going through the data because of the ID 29450 and 3000 in this JSON data sample. My whole database has 1500 ID's. Now I want to print the data `['Id', 'Description', 'StartDate']` in the log from both ID's.

I'm a bit stuck now so hopefully somebody can help on the right track.

Thank you in advance. :)

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');


var fields = ['Id', 'Description', 'StartDate'];


var data = [
  {
    "29450": {
        "Id": "29450",
        "Description": "Lasser Niveau 4",
        "StartDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Company": "",
        "ResponsibilityCenter": "",
        "FunctionGroup": "",
        "City": "",
        "Territory": "",
        "Country": "",
        "Attributes": {
            "Name": {
                "Description": "",
                "Name": ""           
            },
            "WERKTIJDEN": {
                "Description": "Anders",
                "Name": "Werktijden"
            }
        },
        "RequestNo": ""
    },
    "3000": {
        "Id": "3000",
        "Description": "Lasser Niveau 4",
        "StartDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Company": "",
        "ResponsibilityCenter": "",
        "FunctionGroup": "",
        "City": "",
        "Territory": "",
        "Country": "",
        "Attributes": {
            "Name": {
                "Description": "",
                "Name": ""                      
            },
            "WERKTIJDEN": {
                "Description": "Anders",
                "Name": "Werktijden"
            }
        },
        "RequestNo": ""
    },
];


const json2csvParser = new Parser({fields, unwind: ['Id','Description','StartDate'], unwindBlank: true });
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(data);    
fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
  });
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Think you should add another tag for javascript, This is purely a javascript question

Comment: You have singles quotes in excess in `[Id', Description', StartDate'];` (after each member) syntax highlighting helps

Comment: `data` **is not a json** it's a JS object

Comment: Are you using this [json2csv module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv)?

Comment: @Wyck yes i'm using this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv#user-content-json2csv-transform-streaming-api

Comment: You've got `var json = `... but then also do `parse(data)` and `data` would be undefined in this example.  If that's just a mistake, then please fix it in the question.  Should likely be `var data =`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of...

```
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(data);
```

...use...

```
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => data[0][key]));
```

### Full explanation

Your data is in a strange format.  It's an array of one object.  I'm not sure if there would ever be another object in the array, but I have to assume that there won't be.  So `data[0]` is the only relevant object here.

This `data[0]` is what I would call a *index*.  It is an object that has properties that are the primary keys of the objects contained within.  It's useful because you can access `data[0]['1234']` to obtain the object with id `'1234'` in constant time.  It's not clear if it would ever contain any other properties, but again, I'll assume that it won't because it looks a lot like an *index*.

You want to begin by getting all the keys of that one-and-only object of interest with `Object.keys(data[0])`.  If you just map these keys to an array of the value of those properties, then you turn the index back into an regular unindexed array of objects -- and this is what json2csv expects as input.

The meat of the fix is a technique like this:

```
let unindexed = Object.keys(indexed).map(key => indexed[key])
```

It essentially turns this kind of structure...

```
var indexed = {
  "29450": {
      "Id": "29450",
      "Description": "Lasser Niveau 4"
  },
  "3000": {
      "Id": "3000",
      "Description": "Lasser Niveau 4"
  }
};
```

...into this kind of structure...

```
var unindexed = [
  {
    "Id": "29450",
    "Description": "Lasser Niveau 4"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3000",
    "Description": "Lasser Niveau 4"
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you want to access the object but don't know its Id.  You'll have to define how the object is to be distinguished from any other allowable properties in the containing object.  Here's an example that just uses the first key as the one that specifies the object.

*Note, this code is intended to be run in a node.js environment and requires the **json2csv** package*  `npm i json2csv --save`

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');

var fields = ['Id', 'Description', 'StartDate'];

var data = [
  {
    "29450": {
      "Id": "29450",
      "Description": "Lasser Niveau 4",
      "StartDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"

    },
    "RequestNo": ""
  },

  {
    "3000": {
      "Id": "3000",
      "Description": "Lasser Niveau 4",
      "StartDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "RequestNo": ""
  }
];

function getContainedObjectId(container) {
  return Object.keys(container)[0];
}

var flattened = data.map(container => container[getContainedObjectId(container)]);

const json2csvParser = new Parser({ fields, unwind: ['Id', 'Description', 'StartDate'], unwindBlank: true });
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(flattened);
fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('file saved');
});
```

Here we rely on the ID being the first key.  You'll have to define for us how to distinguish the ID from any other properties that may exist.

Here's another way that is potentially more robust.  Search for the first key that looks like an integer (consists of digits 0-9) whose property name matches its value's `Id` property.

```
function getContainedObjectId(container) {
  return Object.keys(container).filter(key => /^[0-9]+$/.test(key) && container[key].Id === key)[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes more sense now. Next problem is now to print it to a CSV. I had a working code but now i'm stuck again. Can you help me on my way with this? I edited my orginal code.

Comment: @Bennie Can you update your question to show what you expect the CSV output to look like, please?

Comment: If updating my question with the expected output :) Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Bennie I edited the answer make it run using json2csv as you requested.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! Problem now is the data because its not looping though the data. I've updated the data. Can look at it one more time please? You would be a great help :)

Comment: You changed the format of your data from the way it was when I answered your original question. Now your example isn't even valid JavaScript.  I assume you're just missing a brace.  In the future please cut and paste known working code.  i assume you now have the (rather needless) format of an array with a single object whose keys are the ids and the values are the objects.  That's a way easier format to work with.  But here's an adapter to make it work with my existing answer:  `data = Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => ({[key]: data[0][key]}));`

Comment: My apologize for the confusing :) Can you update your answer so i can accept it ? :)

Comment: You have changed the structure of your original data so significantly that this answer no longer applies.  Also your original question actually contains a bracing syntax error that makes me worried about what the actual structure of your data was intended to be.  Instead I have down-voted your question (until you fix your syntax errors and explain the structure of the object) and I have provided a different answer that is a much more direct answer to your (now modified) question.

Comment: If you accept my other answer, I'll just delete this one, because it doesn't apply any more now that you have changed the question.

Comment: Assuming this answer gets no up-votes in the near future, my intention is to delete it, since it doesn't agree with the edited question any more.

Comment: that is the way i suppose. Thank you for all your help :)